# RegEx for matching and replacing only column-number-digit from a excel-formula string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to replace columnNumber digit from a excel formula string.

I have tried writing a regex `(/[A-Z]\d+/g)` to get columnNumber with digit  from the formula string which seems not working properly as It's just detecting columnNumber (E2~D2) instead of replacing only the digit of that columnNumber-digit it's replacing the whole columnNumber.

```
var formula = "=IF(E2<(D2*0.004),100,IF((100-(((E2-(D2*0.004))/(D2*0.004))*100))<0,0,(100-(((E2-(D2*0.004))/(D2*0.004))*100))))";
    var regex = /[A-Z]\d+/g;

    for(var i=2; i<=3; i++)
    console.log(formula.replace(regex,i)
```

I need this

```
/** 
=IF(E2<(D2*0.004),100,IF((100-(((E2-(D2*0.004))/(D2*0.004))*100))<0,0,(100-(((E2-(D2*0.004))/(D2*0.004))*100))))

=IF(E3<(D3*0.004),100,IF((100-(((E3-(D3*0.004))/(D3*0.004))*100))<0,0,(100-(((E3-(D3*0.004))/(D3*0.004))*100))))
**/
```

But getting this

```
/** 
=IF(2<(2*0.004),100,IF((100-(((2-(2*0.004))/(2*0.004))*100))<0,0,(100-(((2-(2*0.004))/(2*0.004))*100))))

=IF(3<(3*0.004),100,IF((100-(((3-(3*0.004))/(3*0.004))*100))<0,0,(100-(((3-(3*0.004))/(3*0.004))*100))))
**/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, if you want to replace the digit after [A-Z] or not. If that would be the case, this might help you to do so:

```js
var formula = "=IF(E2<(D2*0.004),100,IF((100-(((E2-(D2*0.004))/(D2*0.004))*100))<0,0,(100-(((E2-(D2*0.004))/(D2*0.004))*100))))";
    var regex = /([A-Z])\d+/g;

    for(var i=2; i<=3; i++){
        console.log(formula.replace(regex,'\$1'+i));
    }
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6lmyUI/1/)

This graph shows how the expression would work:

[image]